# Definite integral problem from the old Polish exam.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that: $\frac{ \pi }{4} \le  \int\limits_{\pi\over4}^{\pi\over2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}\ dx   \le  \frac{\pi}{4}\cdot \frac{ \sqrt{6} }{2}$

I did something like that

$\int\limits_{\pi\over4}^{\pi\over2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2{\pi\over2}}\ dx  \le  \int\limits_{\pi\over4}^{\pi\over2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}\ dx   \le  \int\limits_{\pi\over4}^{\pi\over2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2{\pi\over4}}\ dx $

That is

$\int\limits_{\pi\over4}^{\pi\over2}\ 1 \ dx  \le  \int\limits_{\pi\over4}^{\pi\over2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}\ dx   \le  \int\limits_{\pi\over4}^{\pi\over2}{\sqrt{6}\over2}\ dx$

Which is equal to the thesis.

But my question is this: How to prove it in a different way? Please give me as many ways as possible

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Youll find that questions that just say "prove this" are not received well. What have you tried? where are you stuck??

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality can be proved from $\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}\ge 1$. For the second inequality, we have
$$
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}dx
{
<
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2x+0.25\cos^4x}dx
\\=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{(2+\cos^2x)^2}dx
\\=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}2+\cos^2xdx
\\=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{5+\cos2x}{2}dx
\\=
\frac{5x+0.5\sin2x}{4}\Bigg|_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}
\\=\frac{5\pi-2}{16}.
}
$$
Hence, we have proven a slightly stronger version of the second inequality, since
$$
\frac{5\pi-2}{16}
=
\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{5-2/\pi}{4}
<
\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{5-2/4}{4}
=
\frac{\pi}{4}1.125
<
\frac{\pi}{4}1.2
=
\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{1.44}
<
\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{1.5}
=
\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}.
$$